# How to implement 1 or 2 frames lag between the main and the render thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I've read that engines skip 1 or 2 frames and keep this distance to ensure that the render thread and the main thread won't go too much forward.

I've got a very simple command queue that allows the main thread to queue commands and the render thread to dispatch them, but I don't know how I can keep 1/2 frames distance between these threads.

basic implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

struct CommandQueue
{
    //not thread-safe
    //called only by the main thread
    //collects all gl calls from the main thread
    void Submit(std::function<void()> command)
    {
        commands.push(std::move(command));
    }

    //called only by the main thread
    //when the current frame has finished pushing gl commands
    //we're ready to push them into the render thread
    void Flush()
    {
        { 
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            commandsToExecute = std::move(commands);
        }

        cv.notify_one();
    }

    //called only by the render thread
    //submit gl calls from our queue into the graphics queue
    bool Execute()
    {
        auto renderCommands = WaitForCommands();
        if(renderCommands.empty()) {
            return false;
        }

        while(!renderCommands.empty()) {
            auto cmd = std::move(renderCommands.front());
            renderCommands.pop();

            cmd();
        }

        return true;
    }

    void Quit()
    {
        quit.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        cv.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> WaitForCommands()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return !commandsToExecute.empty() || quit.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); });

        auto result = std::move(commandsToExecute);
        return result;
    }

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> commands;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> commandsToExecute;

    std::atomic_bool quit{false};
};

int main()
{
    CommandQueue commandQueue;

    std::thread renderThread([&](){
        while(true) {
            if(!commandQueue.Execute()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    bool quit = false;
    while(!quit) {
        //example commands...
        commandQueue.Submit([](){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        });
        commandQueue.Submit([](){
            glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        });

        commandQueue.Submit([](){
            glViewport(0, 0, 1600, 900);
        });

        commandQueue.Submit([](){
            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        });

        //notify the render thread that there is work to be done
        commandQueue.Flush();
    }

    commandQueue.Flush();
    commandQueue.Quit();
    renderThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I implement this 1/2 frames lag?

Comment: Do issues occur if you don't let the render thread lag behind?

Comment: Have read of [Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)

Comment: @Jaan Yes. It slows down the application because the main thread pushes too many commands into the render thread. In the result, for example, when I'd want to exit the application it takes like 5 seconds until it finishes all its work. And I think that having only 2 frames running concurrently would be enough.

Comment: @RichardCritten How is that related to graphics and the render thread?

Comment: I'm confused, how is your application slowing down because of the load on the render thread? Isn't the core of your application running on the main thread with any rendering being offloaded to the render thread? The only thread join I see is at the end of your application outside of the main loop so that shouldn't slow anything down.

Comment: My bad. It is not like the frame rate is terrible or something. But when the app closes, it has a whole bunch of work to do when the thread joins. And it also will eventually come with synchronizing with physics when I implement it. GPU resource streaming might take some time, and possibly more things that I don't know about right now. Other applications don't have this lag just because it is fashionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found Filament Engine and it has FrameSkipper class which implements the solution I need.

quick example:

```cpp
//what class should implement Tick functionality?
std::vector<std::function<bool()>> tickFunctions;

void RunAndRemove()
{
    auto it = tickFunctions.begin();
    while (it != tickFunctions.end()) {
        if ((*it)()) {
            it = tickFunctions.erase(it);
        }
        else ++it;
    }
}

void Tick(CommandQueue& queue)
{
    queue.Submit([]() { RunAndRemove(); });
}

struct Fence
{
    Fence(CommandQueue& queue)
            : queue(queue)
    {
        queue.Submit([this]() {
            fence = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);

            std::weak_ptr<Status> weak = result;
            tickFunctions.push_back([this, weak]() {
                auto result = weak.lock();
                if (result) {
                    GLenum status = glClientWaitSync(fence, 0, 0u);
                    result->store(status, std::memory_order_relaxed);

                    return (status != GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED);
                }
                return true;
            });
        });
    }

    ~Fence()
    {
        queue.Submit([fence = fence]() {
            glDeleteSync(fence);
        });
    }

    GLenum getFenceStatus()
    {
        if (!result) {
            return GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED;
        }

        return result->load();
    }

    GLsync fence = nullptr;

    using Status = std::atomic<GLenum>;
    std::shared_ptr<Status> result{ std::make_shared<Status>(GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED) };
    CommandQueue& queue;
};

struct FrameSkipper
{
    FrameSkipper(CommandQueue& queue, size_t latency = 1)
            : queue(queue), last(latency)
    {
    }

    ~FrameSkipper() = default;

    bool Begin()
    {
        auto& syncs = delayedSyncs;
        auto sync = syncs.front();
        if (sync) {
            auto status = sync->getFenceStatus();
            if (status == GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED) {
                // Sync not ready, skip frame
                return false;
            }
            sync.reset();
        }
        // shift all fences down by 1
        std::move(syncs.begin() + 1, syncs.end(), syncs.begin());
        syncs.back() = {};
        return true;
    }

    void End()
    {
        auto& sync = delayedSyncs[last];
        if (sync) {
            sync.reset();
        } sync = std::make_shared<Fence>(queue);
    }

private:
    static constexpr size_t MAX_FRAME_LATENCY = 4;

    using Container = std::array<std::shared_ptr<Fence>, MAX_FRAME_LATENCY>;
    mutable Container delayedSyncs{};

    CommandQueue& queue;

    size_t last;
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    CommandQueue commandQueue;

    std::thread renderThread([&](){
        while(true) {
            if(!commandQueue.Execute()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    FrameSkipper frameSkipper(commandQueue);

    auto BeginFrame = [&]() {
        Tick(commandQueue);

        if(frameSkipper.Begin()) {
            return true;
        }

        commandQueue.Flush();
        return false;
    };


    auto EndFrame = [&]() {
        frameSkipper.End();

        Tick(commandQueue);
        commandQueue.Flush();
    };

    bool quit = false;
    while(!quit) {
        if(BeginFrame()) {
            commandQueue.Submit([](){
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            });
            commandQueue.Submit([](){
                glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            });

            commandQueue.Submit([](){
                glViewport(0, 0, 1600, 900);
            });

            commandQueue.Submit([](){
                SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
            });

            EndFrame();
        }
    }

    commandQueue.Flush();
    commandQueue.Quit();
    renderThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```